# Laptop with good hardware, similar to a MacBook Pro

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, macbook

I love the Macbook Pro. It *is* a great hardware. The all aluminium without any screws is a turn-on :) . The display, keyboard etc make it *awesomer*.

Now, I'd love to buy a Macbook pro itself, but I am so used to working on Ubuntu being my primary development environment, I like it, and don't want to change.

Now, the question is, **What other laptops are out there that have a hardware comparable to the Macbook pro; play well with Linux (drivers etc); and preferably ship without Windows**

Comment: You know that you can install Linux on a MacBook? (if the price is not an issue)

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu runs great on MBP hardware

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has screws

Answer (score 3):

If you must have Ubuntu, you can either [install it natively](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro) or try [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and use an Ubuntu VM. Of course, could also give OS X a try. There are plenty of *nix hackers who use OS X as their main dev machine.

Comment: +1. I dev primarily on a (slightly older) MacBook Pro, and my work ranges from OS internals to databases to iPhone apps. So far I haven't found anything a MacBook won't do (unless you're a Visual Studio dev).